# Is __init__ necessary if it only calls super.__init__?

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7, inheritance, python-multithreading

I'm subclassing the `threading.Thread` class and it currently looks like this:

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self:
        super(MyThread, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        # Do some stuff
```

Is the `__init__` required in this instance? If I leave it out, is it called automatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not needed in this case.

When instantiating a class, if it has no `__init__` method, the `__init__` method of the super class is automatically called.